# Orthogonal polynomials with respect to $\langle u , v\rangle$ = $\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-|x|}u(x)v(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

Consider in the space of continuous functions defined in $[-1, 1]$ with real values the inner product $\langle u , v\rangle$ = $\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-|x|}u(x)v(x)dx$.

How can I determine polynomials $q_j(x)$, $j = 0, 1, 2, 3$ of degree $j$ that are mutually orthogonal with respect to this inner product?

Comment: Consider $p_j(x) = x^j$ and apply Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: What does "two by two orthogonal" mean?

Comment: @copper.hat It is the litteral translation from the expression in spanish or french for "mutually orthogonal"

Comment: @JeanMarie Interesting.  I think I've seen this as "pairwise orthogonal", but since orthogonality is a pairwise relation, I suppose "mutually orthogonal" is harmless (as opposed to e.g. its generalization in Probability to independence).  Now that I'm looking for it, I see both terms used, but I'm curious if the difference is regional in nature.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks! That was linguistically insensitive of me, a hazard of being a monoglot :-(.

Comment: What is your work on the subject ? Have you realized that parity property (odd/even) of the looked for polynomials can guide you ?

Comment: Hint (without Gram-Schmidt): A sufficient condition for having $\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-|x|}u(x)v(x)dx=0$ is that the product $u(x)v(x)$ is an odd function. This gives  polynomials $p_0(x)=1,p_1(x)=x,p_2(x)=x^2-k$ (for a certain $k$ : do you see how to find it ?). It remains to find the 3 coefficients $a,b,c$ in $p_3(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$: express the 3 orthogonality conditions wrt the other $p_k$s: this will give you 3 equations...